# Как вывести таблицу связанную способом много ко многим в sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Есть связывающая таблица с 4 ячейками. id, info, id-otdel, id-subotdel
info переменная которую я передаю. Мне нужно вывести запрос из id-subotdel если info и id-otdel соответствуют условию.
Есть пример того как это можно сделать, а не писать кучу if? Сделать запрос который в связывающей таблице найдет все строки с совпадениями и выведет